# glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer:

Tags: c++, linux, runtime-error, delete-operator

There are many questions like this but after looking at some cases, I guess this question is case-specific so I post my code and pointed out where the problem takes place may you be patient reading my code?

#### uniBTree.h

```
#ifndef uniBTree_H
#define uniBTree_H

#include "uniTreeNode.h"
#include <cassert>

template<class T>
class uniBTree {
    private:
      uniTreeNode<T> *root;
      int delete_helper(uniTreeNode<T> *);
      uniTreeNode<T> *insert_helper(uniTreeNode<T> *, const T);
      void in_print_helper(const uniTreeNode<T> *) const;
      void pre_print_helper(const uniTreeNode<T> *) const;
      void post_print_helper(const uniTreeNode<T> *) const;

    public:
      uniBTree(void);
      uniBTree(uniTreeNode<T> *r);
      ~uniBTree(void);
      void insert(const T i);
      void in_print(void) const;
      void pre_print(void) const;
      void post_print(void) const;
};

template<class T>
uniBTree<T>::uniBTree(void)
{
    root = NULL;
}

template<class T>
uniBTree<T>::uniBTree(uniTreeNode<T> *r)
{
    root = r;
}

template<class T>
int uniBTree<T>::delete_helper(uniTreeNode<T> *n)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (n == NULL)
        return 0;

    count += delete_helper(n->get_left());
    count += delete_helper(n->get_right());
    delete n;
    count++;
    return count;
}

template<class T>
uniBTree<T>::~uniBTree(void)
{
    int count = delete_helper(root);
    std::cout << "uniBTree<T>::~uniBTree<T>(void)\n";
    std::cout << count << " nodes deleted\n";
}

template<class T>
void uniBTree<T>::in_print() const
{
    in_print_helper(root);
}

template<class T>
void uniBTree<T>::pre_print() const
{
    pre_print_helper(root);
}

template<class T>
void uniBTree<T>::post_print() const
{
    post_print_helper(root);
}

template<class T>
void uniBTree<T>::in_print_helper(const uniTreeNode<T> *current) const
{
    if (current == NULL)
        return;
    in_print_helper(current->get_left());
    current->print();
    in_print_helper(current->get_right());
}

template<class T>
void uniBTree<T>::pre_print_helper(const uniTreeNode<T> *current) const
{
    if (current == NULL)
        return;
    current->print();
    pre_print_helper(current->get_left());
    pre_print_helper(current->get_right());
}

template<class T>
void uniBTree<T>::post_print_helper(const uniTreeNode<T> *current) const
{
    if (current == NULL)
        return;
    post_print_helper(current->get_left());
    post_print_helper(current->get_right());
    current->print();
}

template<class T>
void uniBTree<T>::insert(const T i)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        root = new uniTreeNode<T>(i, NULL, NULL);
    else
        insert_helper(root, i);
}

template<class T>
uniTreeNode<T> *uniBTree<T>::insert_helper(uniTreeNode<T> *current, const T i)
{
    if (current == NULL) {//this is will only dealed by attempting to visit leaves...
        //if root is null, it'll be handled in insert
        uniTreeNode<T> *child = new uniTreeNode<T>(i, NULL, NULL);
        assert(child != NULL);
        return(child);
    }
    if (i < current->get_data()) 
        current->set_left(insert_helper(current->get_left(), i));
    else 
        current->set_right(insert_helper(current->get_right(), i));
    return(current);
}

#endif
```

#### uniTreeNode.h

```
#ifndef uniTreeNode_H//for redefinition
#define uniTreeNode_H

#include <iostream>
//using namespace std; don't use using namespace xxx and include source file in .h file

template<typename T>
class uniTreeNode {
     private:
         T data;
         uniTreeNode<T> *left;
         uniTreeNode<T> *right;
     public:
         //uniTreeNode<T>(void);
         uniTreeNode(T d, uniTreeNode<T> *l, uniTreeNode<T> *r);
         T get_data(void) const;
         uniTreeNode<T> *get_left(void) const;
         uniTreeNode<T> *get_right(void) const;
         void set_left(uniTreeNode<T> *l);
         void set_right(uniTreeNode<T> *r);
         void print() const;
};

template<typename T>
uniTreeNode<T>::uniTreeNode/*remember syntax here*/
(T d , uniTreeNode<T> *l = NULL, uniTreeNode<T> *r = NULL)
{
     data = d;
     left = l;
     right = r;
}

template<typename T>
T uniTreeNode<T>::get_data(void) const
{
     return data;
}

template<typename T>
uniTreeNode<T> * uniTreeNode<T>::get_left(void) const
{
    return left;
}

template<typename T>
uniTreeNode<T> * uniTreeNode<T>::get_right(void) const
{
    return right;
}

template<typename T>
void uniTreeNode<T>::set_left(uniTreeNode<T> *l)
{
    left = l;
}

template<typename T>
void uniTreeNode<T>::set_right(uniTreeNode<T> *r)
{
    right = r;
}

template<typename T>
void uniTreeNode<T>::print() const
{
   std::cout << "data is " << data << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

#### date.h

```
#include <ostream>
class date{
    private:
            int y;
            int m;
            int d;
    public:
            date();//default constructor
            date(const long int);//used by cplr as convert constructor
            date(int, int , int);
            friend bool operator<(const date &d1, const date &d2);//d1 is for left-hand date
            friend bool operator>(const date &d1, const date &d2);
            bool operator==(date d);
            bool operator!=(date d);
            date &operator=(date d);
            friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, date d);
            friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, date d);
};
```

#### date.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "date.h"

date::date(){
    y = m = d = 0;
}

date::date(int Y, int M, int D){
    y = Y;
    m = M;
    d = D;
}

date::date(const long int s){//#second since 1970/1/1 00:00:00
    struct tm *buf;
    buf = gmtime(&s);
    y = (buf->tm_year+1900);
    m = buf->tm_mon+1;
    d = buf->tm_mday;
}

bool operator<(const date &d1, const date &d2){
     bool result;//sizeof(bool) is 1
     if(d1.y < d2.y) result = true;
     else if(d1.y == d2.y){
           if(d1.m < d2.m) result = true;
           else if(d1.m == d2.m){
                   if(d1.d < d2.d) result = true;
                   else result = false;
           }
           else result = false;
     }
     else result = false;

     return result;
}

bool operator>(const date &d1, const date &d2){
    bool result;//sizeof(bool) is 1
    if(d1.y > d2.y) result = true;
    else if(d1.y == d2.y){
            if(d1.m > d2.m) result = true;
            else if(d1.m == d2.m){
                    if(d1.d > d2.d) result = true;
                    else result = false;
            }
            else result = false;
    }
    else result = false;

    return result;
}

bool date::operator==(date d){
    return (this->y==d.y && this->m==d.m && this->d==d.d); 
}

bool date::operator!=(date d){
    return (this->y!=d.y || this->m!=d.m || this->d!=d.d);
}

date &date::operator=(date d){
    this->y = d.y;
    this->m = d.m;
    this->d = d.d;
    return *this;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, date d){
    out << d.y << "/" << d.m << "/" << d.d << std::endl;
    return out;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, date d){
    in >> d.y >> d.m >> d.d ;
    return in;
}
```

#### main function

```
#include "uniBTree.h"
#include "date.h"
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    date d1 = 100000000;//convert constructor
    uniTreeNode<date> node(d1, NULL, NULL);
    printf("%p %p\n", node.get_left(), node.get_right());
    std::cout << node.get_data() << std::endl;


    date d2 = 86401;
    date d3 = 200000000;

    uniBTree<date> btree(&node);

    return 0;
}
```

I tested and found that its `&node` that is invalid. I think it is because it tries to "release" `btree` at the end of the program and when the root is encountered, because it points to `node`, it can't perform good thing.

I have two question:

1. if construct a `node` like what I did,(`uniTreeNode<date> node(xxx, xxx, xxx);`) was the object "NEW"ed by the program?
2. for the `uniTreeNode<T>` class template, I didn't write its destructor!! So, like what I say above, when node,which is pointed by root of `btree`, is to be released is there so-called "default destructor"? and is it called here ? And most importantly, is "DELETE" used by the program?

If one of the two question above is no, is it why the problem arise?

EDIT: now the problem is shown, but how can I adjust my code to fix this? any one any idea?

EDIT: just modify like this:

```
uniTreeNode<date> *nodeptr = new uniTreeNode<date>(d1, NULL, NULL);
```

p.s. if not indirectly using a pointer to refer to our root of the btree(thus using new), new isn't used, and delete shouldn't be used; by this choice, delete_helper of uniTreenode should use this:

```
if(n != root){
    delete n;
    count++;
}
```

but this does not solve the problem...
the ultimate question is:

```
"can we release object without using delete(because it isn't obtained from newing) in c++?"
```

REPLY:

My "release"/"allocated" is actually saying about the memory, without specifying HOW it is done...but it's a big issue anyway

You say "you can do that but it is almost always the wrong answer";you mean that I should use DELETE but not directly call the destructor?(actually that doesn't seem proper at all)
-->please justify here

Btw, for those instance NEWed by me, is it necessary for them to be DELETED by a statement if I want to release them? or they'll also be dealt like those automatic variable instance?(back when out of scope, by compiler)
-->please correct the above if needed

another Q: isn't there ANY existing statement I can use to do things, like  what DELETE does, for those automatic instance? or, I can only call destructor, if I wish?

Comment: What do you mean by "release"? Release the memory allocated by new is what I usually use it for. Perhaps you mean run the destructor? You can do that but it is almost always the wrong answer. An object that is not allocated (using new for example) can only have one "owner" (the function or object it is declared in) so the compiler automatically adds the calls to the destructor where appropriate for such an object.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your questions:

1. No, it allocated memory on the stack at compilation time and just ran the constructor on that.
2. You can't delete a pointer not allocated using new. The compiler inserts a call to the destructor (default or not) for uniTreeNode when the object node is done in main().

So to surmise, you cannot use delete on a pointer that is not allocated using new.

Simplest fix would be to allocate node using new:

```
uniTreeNode<date>* node = new uniTreeNode<date>(d1);

uniBTree<date> btree(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use `valgrind`.

It tells you right away what the problem is, you're deleting a stack object in the `uniBTree` destructor

```
==23648== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==23648==    at 0x4A0736C: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==23648==    by 0x400D78: uniBTree<date>::delete_helper(uniTreeNode<date>*) (uniBTree.h:48)
==23648==    by 0x400CD5: uniBTree<date>::~uniBTree() (uniBTree.h:56)
==23648==    by 0x400B91: main (main.cc:17)
==23648==  Address 0x7fefffab0 is on thread 1's stack
==23648==
```

The destructor calls `delete` but `&node` was not created by `new` (you can tell that because you didn't write `new`!)

Comment: thx
in fact I know about the existence of such debugging tool

Comment: thank you so much
actually I know about valgrind
but I am not familiar with using it
I'll learn about it!!